# Vagrant login fails

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, vagrant, sudo

When I log in to my VirtualBox machine using Vagrant like this

vagrant ssh

and then run

sudo su -
tail /var/log/messages

I see the following errors

[image]

Any idea why I'm getting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The box you're using is misconfigured, but not in a critical way. It looks like the dhclient configuration isn't properly setup. I'd ignore this as its probably not an issue unless it is actually preventing parts of the system from working.